# Jmeter JSON query limited to max 50 how do I interate through 1000s of pages, 1 thread 1 user

Tags: loops, jmeter

Newbie to Jmeter..I have a large Json query over 10000 responses to be run once daily by 1 user. I want to test how long it will take to go through all pages, however the page size has been restricted to 50 per page.. 1st page is at 0. 
I know I can have 100s of Http Requests and change the page number on each and it will run. but What do I need to set to the iterate the pageNumber without listing 100's of HTTP Requests

Body

```
{
  "EmployeID": "78123",
  "startDate": "2016-01-01",
  "endDate": "2016-01-02",
  "pageNumber": "0",
  "pageSize": "50"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it
Changed body to

```
{
  "EmployeID": "78123",
  "startDate": "2016-01-01",
  "endDate": "2016-01-02",
  "pageNumber": "${count},
  "pageSize": "50"
}
```

added a **Parent Loop controller** and set

```
count = 1000
Counter Start = 0
increment = 1
reference Name = count
```